# Group many arrays into one based on object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-2016

I'm working on an e-commerce website. I have to manage product variations. The REST API response looks something like this:

```
"variations": [
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "L"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "XXL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "Azul"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "M"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "S"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "XL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "Azul"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "S"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "M"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This JSON is inefficient for me to work on the frontend. It's difficult to group variations based on its type (name) and values (valueName) since they are on different "array of arrays".

The final result should be something like this:

```
variations: [
  {
    name: 'Color',
    values: ['Gris', 'Azul']
  },
  {
    name: 'Talle',
    values: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL']
  }
]
```

So far I've achieved this result:

```
[
  { name: "Color", values: ["GRIS"] },
  { name: "Talle", values: ["L"] },
  { name: "Color", values: ["GRIS"] },
  { name: "Talle", values: ["XXL"] },
  { name: "Color", values: ["Azul"] },
  { name: "Talle", values: ["M"] },
  { name: "Color", values: ["GRIS"] },
  { name: "Talle", values: ["S"] },
  { name: "Color", values: ["GRIS"] },
  { name: "Talle", values: ["XL"] },
  { name: "Color", values: ["Azul"] },
  { name: "Talle", values: ["S"] },
  { name: "Color", values: ["GRIS"] },
  { name: "Talle", values: ["M"] }
]
```

Based on this code:

```
let variations = this.$page.product.variations;
let newArr = [];

variations.forEach(variation => {
        newArr.push(
          Object.values(
            variation.attributeCombinations.reduce(
              (result, { name, valueName }) => {
                // Create new group
                if (!result[name]) {
                  result[name] = {
                    name,
                    values: []
                  };
                }
                // Append to group
                result[name].values.push(valueName);

                return result;
              },
              {}
            )
          )
        );
      });
return newArr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur));
```

Comment: Your desired output has loss of information compared to the original structure. For instance, the original structure does not have the combination Azul-XL. This information cannot be derived from your desired output. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @trincot Yes! I had noticed that. However, for now, and the specific use case I will give to this functionality, it's not really a problem. Thank you though!

Comment: So did any of the answers suit your needs? Or are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: Naga's answer was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce , forEach and index of each loop

1. Loop through variations array
2. For first index at position 0, push to Accumulator (acc)
3. Use second loop using .forEach to loop through attributeCombinations
4. Push valueNames to corresponding names- Color and Talle

```js
var arr = {"variations": [
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "L"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "XXL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "Azul"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "M"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "S"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "XL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "Azul"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "S"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributeCombinations": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "valueName": "GRIS"
      },
      {
        "name": "Talle",
        "valueName": "M"
      }
    ]
  }
]
          }


console.log(arr.variations.reduce((acc, val, idx) => {
  val.attributeCombinations.forEach((v, i) => {
  if(idx === 0) {
    acc.push({name: v.name , valueName:  Array.of(v.valueName)})
  }else{
    i === 0 ? acc[0].valueName.push(v.valueName) : acc[1].valueName.push(v.valueName) 
  }
})
  return acc
},[]).map(v => v = {name :v.name,  valueName: [...new Set(v.valueName)]}));
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZZxVzp?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the array and summarize into an object. Use `forEach` to loop thru the `attributeCombinations` and construct the desired output. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var variations = [{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"L"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"XXL"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"Azul"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"M"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"S"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"XL"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"Azul"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"S"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"M"}]}];

var result = Object.values(variations.reduce((c, v) => {
  v.attributeCombinations.forEach(({name,valueName}) => {
    c[name] = c[name] || {name,values: []}
    c[name].values.push(valueName);
  });
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

---

If you want unique values, you can use `Set` and add another loop to convert the `Set` object into an array.

```js
var variations = [{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"L"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"XXL"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"Azul"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"M"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"S"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"XL"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"Azul"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"S"}]},{"attributeCombinations":[{"name":"Color","valueName":"GRIS"},{"name":"Talle","valueName":"M"}]}]

var result = Object.values(variations.reduce((c, v) => {
  v.attributeCombinations.forEach(({name,valueName}) => {
    c[name] = c[name] || {name,values: new Set}
    c[name].values.add(valueName);
  });
  return c;
}, {})).map(o => {
  o.values = [...o.values.values()]
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` for extracting the values.

The object `Set` provides a way to remove repeated values.

```js
let variations = [   {     "attributeCombinations": [       {         "name": "Color",         "valueName": "GRIS"       },       {         "name": "Talle",         "valueName": "L"       }     ]   },   {     "attributeCombinations": [       {         "name": "Color",         "valueName": "GRIS"       },       {         "name": "Talle",         "valueName": "XXL"       }     ]   },   {     "attributeCombinations": [       {         "name": "Color",         "valueName": "Azul"       },       {         "name": "Talle",         "valueName": "M"       }     ]   },   {     "attributeCombinations": [       {         "name": "Color",         "valueName": "GRIS"       },       {         "name": "Talle",         "valueName": "S"       }     ]   },   {     "attributeCombinations": [       {         "name": "Color",         "valueName": "GRIS"       },       {         "name": "Talle",         "valueName": "XL"       }     ]   },   {     "attributeCombinations": [       {         "name": "Color",         "valueName": "Azul"       },       {         "name": "Talle",         "valueName": "S"       }     ]   },   {     "attributeCombinations": [       {         "name": "Color",         "valueName": "GRIS"       },       {         "name": "Talle",         "valueName": "M"       }     ]   } ];
let result = Object.values(variations.reduce((a, {attributeCombinations: combinations}) => {
  combinations.forEach(({name, valueName}) => {
    (a[name] || (a[name] = {name, values: new Set()})).values.add(valueName);
  });
  
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(Array.from(result[0].values));// for understanding the object set
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: I didn't know about the Set object. Your code is really clean! The result isn't exactly what I needed, but your help is much appreciated. Thank you!